# How to manipulate object properties in a promise without returning any data?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, javascript-objects

**What I am trying to do:** I want to write a object method to fetch data from a MySql database and set the object properties according to the result of the MySql query.

**I already achieved this behavoiur** using async, await and promises. But im not sure if this is the right way to manipulate the object properties in the promise created in `async fetchGame(id)`.

**My actual question is:** Is this the right way of doing it? How should I check if the object properties were set correctly and return either `resolve('done')` or `resolve('error')`?

**Code Structure:**

I have a `Game` class with the properties id, player1 and player2 and a method called `async fetchGame(id)`.

The `Game` Object gets initialized in an other file called index.js.

The database connection gets initialized in mySqlConnection.js.

Please notice that proper try, catch error handling is not implemented yet.

**object.js:**

```
const db = require('../mySqlConnection');

class Game{
    constructor(){
        this.id = null;
        this.player1 = null;
        this.player2 = null;
    }

    async fetchGame(id){
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const sql = "SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `id`=" +id

            let data = await db.promise(sql);

            this.id = data[0].id;
            this.player1 = data[0].player1;
            this.player2 = data[0].player2;

            if(this.id != null){
                resolve("done");
            } else{
                reject("error")
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

**mySqlConnection.js:**

```
db.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});

db.promise = (sql) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                reject(new Error());
            }
            else{
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
};

module.exports = db
```

**index.js:**

```
async function createGame(){
    
    var firstGame = new Game()
    await firstGame.fetchGame(1)

    console.log("index.js: " +JSON.stringify(firstGame))
}


createGame();
```

console.log Output (as expected): `index.js: {"id":1,"player1":"NameOfPlayer1","player2":"NameOfPlayer2"}`

Comment: There's no need to use `return new Promise()` when the function is declared `async`, since that automatically makes it return a promise.

Comment: Thanks didn't know that! I am pretty new to the promise concept :)

Comment: i think you need to use `Promise.all()`

Comment: If the promise function calls `reject()` this will be turned into an exception when you `await` it. You should use `try/catch` to detect whether the promise was resolved or rejected.

Comment: @Jud3v Why? There aren't multiple promises.

Comment: @Barmar Please consider that proper try, catch error handling is not implemented yet :)

Comment: That's what you need to do to "check if the object properties were set correctly and return either resolve('done') or resolve('error')"

Comment: @Barmar Alright, just like so `if( (this.id != data[0].id) || (this.player1 != data[0].player1)  || (...) ) { resolve('error') }`? Any other improvements?

Comment: What's wrong with the `if` statement you currently have, that either calls `resolve()` or `reject()`?

Comment: @Barmar I thought it makes more sense to check all of the properties, but probably that's not necessary

Comment: You should probably just check whether `data.length > 0`